# serial port thread goes to standby

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

In my program i have to response to event SerialPort.PinChanged.
That event indicates that device was connected.
Then it sends me a request, i'm answering with some data.
Then this device connecting via RF to base.
And there is another thread, that downloads file via Ethernet every 10 seconds, from that base.

There will be up to 20 serial ports on PC.
So I making thread, that opens it's own serial port.
Then this thread sybscribe my method CheckPluggInState to event SerialPort.PinChanged.
My class have it's own events about device state.
And all work done based on events and responding to this events.

But after about 10 minutes after start, SerialPort.PinChanged not fireing up...
If i connect devices after start - all ok, SerialPort.PinChanged fires up and program do it's work well.
But if i start program and try to connect device when 10 minutes elapsed after start - nothing happen.

So the question - why threads with serial ports didn't response after about 10 minutes?
What is the reason?

I have googled it. In one article author said about thread going to standby state.

Comment: It is probably the serial port driver you are using.  You should use a driver that is recommended by the vendor of the hardware.  Then check if there are any updates to driver and any know issues from the website.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check.

Comment: Updated driver. Nothing changed. I suspect the CP2102. It can enter suspend state. The solution was to check DsrHolding in loop.